# Doing math with sprintf

Tags: printf, gnuplot

When creating a label for GNUplot, reading from text files, how would I get the difference in hours:minutes from two columns which each contain an H:M timestamp (e.g. 23.42).
For example, this creates a concatenation of two columns for an existing label:

```
myDate(col1,col3)=sprintf("%s-%s",strcol(1),strcol(3))
```

Is it possible modify it to do that date math to get something like:

```
 timeDiffLabel(col5,col6)=sprintf(do-some-math-here,strcol(5),strcol(6))
```

Comment: Maybe you can "do math with sprintf()", if you're clever enough.  And maybe you can eat a string bean through your nose, too.  I'd discourage you from trying either.  Just "do the math" to a variable (of the appropriate time), and format the variable with "xxprintf()".  IMHO...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To parse a time, use the `strptime` function:

```
print strptime('%H:%M', '12:34')
```

This prints `45240.0`, which is the number of seconds parsed from the time string.

If you parse the strings from the two columns like this, you can subtract the values and reformat the result with `strftime`:

```
timeDiff(c1, c2) = strftime('%k:%M', strptime('%H:%M', strcol(c2)) - strptime('%H:%M', strcol(c1)))
plot 'test.dat' using 0:0:(timeDiff(1,2)) with labels
```

This works in principle, but only for positive differences. If the difference is e.g. `-1`, you'll get `23`, because the `str*time` functions work on datetimes.

A more sophisticated solution uses only the absolute value of the difference for the actual formatting, and prepends an optional `-` to the result:

```
timeDiff(c1, c2) = (diff = strptime('%H:%M', strcol(c2)) - strptime('%H:%M', strcol(c1)), (diff < 0 ? '-' : '').strftime('%k:%M', abs(diff)))
plot 'test.dat' using 0:0:(timeDiff(1,2)) with labels
```

So, with a test file like

```
12:34  23:54
13:45  11:44
2:33   1:11
```

you get

[image]